# What effect does editing have on downvote reversal?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I know that one of the theories of downvotes is that if people change their post to address the downvote concerns, the downvotes might be reversed. I was wondering if there are any statistics that would indicate what effect the editing of posts has on the frequency of downvote reversal. Although I'm mostly concerned about SO, I would be interested in MSO stats as well.

Comment: No clue, but my guess is that the ratio of meaningful edits to vote reversals decays exponentially with time (so the longer between the vote and the edit, the less likely that there is a reversal).

Comment: How would we measure this? We'd basically need to compare edits after downvotes followed by either a downvote reversal, or no action. But how can we be sure that an edit was in response to a downvote? I've seen plenty of situations where a downvote occurred with a comment, and the post was edited to change something else completely.

Comment: @Dukeling We can't. :-) But if we see that the edits on average have _no_ effect on downvote reversal, I think we can be pretty sure that the theory they do is false.

Comment: Frequency compared to what? If the post *isn't* edited then it is not possible to reverse a downvote after 5 minutes. So the frequency of downvote reversal in that case will be zero.

Comment: I know for a fact that there are vote reversals, and (last time I checked) you can only reverse a vote after an edit (or right after you cast it, which can be thought of as simply changing your mind based on the unedited post, i.e. never having cast the vote). So 100% of reversed downvotes were after edits. See the problem?

Comment: for posts _I_ downvote, reversal rate is probably like 90%. I typically [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/165773) when voting down and I regularly review comments listed in my profile to find out if posts were edited to address my concerns. When this happens (per my recollection, satisfactory edits happen in 90-95% cases), I revert my vote

Comment: @Dukeling Oops ;-) I'd forgotten about the time/edit requirement. I guess the only thing you could show is the average likelihood of downvote reversal. I was very surprised by gnat's hypothesized 90% estimate.  I would have guessed maybe 50% for SO and perhaps 5% (or maybe .5% ;-)) for MSO.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin gnat's 90% is probably based on those where he gets a "Edited" reply to his downvote comment. Firstly, not all downvotes have a comment attached (most downvotes probably **don't** have a comment). Secondly, there isn't always an "Edited" reply.

Comment: @Dukeling Hmmm. Do "Edited" replies occur if you've downvoted but not commented? If the behavior is different, then that's something that could be compared (i.e. difference in reversal rate between those who have left a comment and those who haven't).

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Well, you can't notify a downvoter, so there can't be "edited" replies if the downvoter didn't comment. But a downvoter may stick around for a while, checking for an edit (but, in this case, a comment is unlikely to do much - simply seeing that the post has been edited should be sufficient). And then there are certain people who (/ cases where one) just downvote(s) and leave - this is unlikely to be combined with a comment, and unlikely to be reversed. So, a downvote without a comment should be less likely to be reversed.

Comment: @dukeling Ok, so w/ vs w/o comments could be compared in any case. As for notifying downvoters, though, the _system_ could certainly notify them, right? Or is that information really not kept _at all_? (I assumed it was present but hidden).

Comment: The system *could* notify them, but I'm pretty sure that that feature has been suggested and declined a few times already (just don't ask me to find such a request). (the information is kept, otherwise the arrow won't be highlighted after you've voted, and you'd be able to vote multiple times)